# python multiline quotes syntax error

Tags: python

I'm currently making a Python script which is to print html code to a .html document. I'm using multiline strings by doing triple quotation marks. The thing is that I need to have variables within the code e. g. "fagTitle1" etc. However, when I try to end the multiline string, it tells me that there is syntax error.

```
File "quickstart.py", line 98
   <h2>'''("'")''' + '''(fagTitle1)''' + '''("'")'''</h2>
          ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
def filerino():
file=open("plan.txt", "r")


file=open("App.html", "w")
file.write('''
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>InstaPlan</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="fag1"
      <h2>'''("'")''' + '''(fagTitle1)''' + '''("'")'''</h2>
      <p>("'") + (fagContent1) + ("'")</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fag2"
      <h2>("'") + (fagTitle2) + ("'")</h2>
      <p>("'") + (fagContent1) + ("'")</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fag3"
      <h2>("'") + (fagTitle3) + ("'")</h2>
      <p>("'") + (fagContent1) + ("'")</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
''')
```

Comment: Are you trying to substitute content into the header tags?  If so, using a templating solution is probably a much more maintainable approach (e.g. `jinja2`).  Templating solutions will also allow you to handle things like html escaping to make sure that the markup is safe for the consumer.

Comment: I *think* you are looking for string interpolation here, but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I assume you are trying to put single quote `'` around your variables, if not, simply remove them ...*

---

You need to add + between you concatenation..

```
'''...<h2>''' + "'" + fagTitle1 + "'" + '''</h2>...'''
```

Alternatively, using string.format() you can have clearer code:

```
'''
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>InstaPlan</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="fag1"
      <h2>'{fagTitle1}'</h2>
      <p>'{fagContent1}'</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fag2"
      <h2>'{fagTitle2}'</h2>
      <p>'{fagContent1}'</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fag3"
      <h2>'{fagTitle3}'</h2>
      <p>'{fagContent1}'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
'''.format({
    fagTitle1=fagTitle1,
    fagTitle2=fagTitle2,
    fagContent1=fagContent1
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are already using triple single quotes inside your string, you will not be able to use triple single quotes to wrap your string. Simply change the outside triple single quotes to triple double quotes:

```
file.write("""
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>InstaPlan</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="fag1"
      <h2>'''("'")''' + '''(fagTitle1)''' + '''("'")'''</h2>
      <p>("'") + (fagContent1) + ("'")</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fag2"
      <h2>("'") + (fagTitle2) + ("'")</h2>
      <p>("'") + (fagContent1) + ("'")</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fag3"
      <h2>("'") + (fagTitle3) + ("'")</h2>
      <p>("'") + (fagContent1) + ("'")</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
""")
```

Comment: The single quotes aren't the problem. The thing is that I have to "unstring" the file whenever I'm adding a variable and then "restring" it after the variable is over...

Comment: @Toasterino these are details you need to provide to give context to people reading your questions. As is, there is not much to go on other than to assume what is going on. If that is the case, I would highly consider reading the comment made to your question by mgilson about using something like jinja2